# Opening a custom bash function in a new st terminal

Tags: bash, neovim, x-st

I am trying to execute this custom function stored in my `.bashrc`

```
function nvrcreate {
    NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/Unity nvim
}
```

on a new terminal. This command by itself creates a socket for neovim to listen to. If I execute it in a terminal it works great, but I can't get it to work as a single command that opens a new terminal and executes it.

I am using `st` (suckless / simple terminal) on Manjaro linux.
I have tried it using `nohup` and the `-e` flag that allows `st` to execute a command on opening a new terminal, but couldn't manage to have it working.

Also, in most of my attempts, I have gotten some kind of `child exited with status 1`, and sometimes it simply works for a fraction of a second and then exits.

Comment: Functions are local to each shell. You need to source the script that defines the function in the new terminal's shell.

Comment: I have it in my .bashrc, so it should be sourced, shouldn't it?

Comment: `.bashrc` is only sourced by bash. If you have `st` run `nvrcreate` *instead of* bash, then obviously it won't work.

Comment: In that case, is there any way to do what I ask for? I have seen some people use ```bash -c``` in order to get similar things working, but I simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: This kind of code would be better off in a script than in a function since it doesn't depend on the shell environment, but since you want it as a function, `bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc && nvrcreate'` might be an option.

Comment: I ended up doing what you suggested and divided the commands in scripts that are in the PATH, so I don't have to source them or be in a specific folder. Thanks for your help!